# Twitter API - How to store JSON in Array?

Tags: php, twitter

I'm trying to get the number of followers, follows, tweets, etc. for a user.

I found this api call http://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.json?screen_name=barackobama

How do I take that json result and store it in an array?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use json_decode and set the second parameter to true:

```
$json = file_get_contents("http://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.json?screen_name=barackobama");
$json_array = json_decode($json, true);
```

Of course for file_get_contents() to work with an URL, you have to have [allow_url_fopen](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) directive enabled in your php.ini.